# Opacity by numeric vector

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a [very stylized line chart](https://plot.ly/r/line-charts/#style-line-plots) and I would like to plot all my lines in with one `add_trace`-command, in the hope that this makes my code neater.

I have two issues:

1. I want a lower opacity for the `high`-lines and full opacity for the `low` lines. If I try it seems to assign the opacity randomly.
2. I want the upper lines to be solid and the lower ones to be dashed. The opposite happens.

Concerning these issues I have two questions:

1. Can this 'strange' (not logical) behaviour of `plotly` be fixed? Maybe by using some `layout` option?
2. Does this 'strange' behaviour occur because I am trailing of the path?

The `plotly` examples usually tell you to write a new `add_trace` function for every line or other object you had. I am trying to implement all my lines with one `add_trace`-function.

In my real data, I have more than ten lines to draw and it would really help if I could draw some of the lines together. Here are some sample graph and data:

[image]

I tried with this code:

```
month <- c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
           'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
high_2000 <- c(32.5, 37.6, 49.9, 53.0, 69.1, 75.4, 76.5, 76.6, 70.7, 60.6, 45.1, 29.3)
low_2000 <- c(13.8, 22.3, 32.5, 37.2, 49.9, 56.1, 57.7, 58.3, 51.2, 42.8, 31.6, 15.9)
high_2007 <- c(36.5, 26.6, 43.6, 52.3, 71.5, 81.4, 80.5, 82.2, 76.0, 67.3, 46.1, 35.0)
low_2007 <- c(23.6, 14.0, 27.0, 36.8, 47.6, 57.7, 58.9, 61.2, 53.3, 48.5, 31.0, 23.6)
high_2014 <- c(28.8, 28.5, 37.0, 56.8, 69.7, 79.7, 78.5, 77.8, 74.1, 62.6, 45.3, 39.9)
low_2014 <- c(12.7, 14.3, 18.6, 35.5, 49.9, 58.0, 60.0, 58.6, 51.7, 45.2, 32.2, 29.1)

data <- data.frame(month, high_2000, low_2000, high_2007, low_2007, high_2014, low_2014)

library(plotly)
df<-tidyr::gather(data,key,values,-month)


plot_ly(data=df,x=~month,y=~values,split=~key,type="scatter",
        mode="lines",opacity=ifelse(grepl('high',df$key),0.5,1),line=list(color='#1f77b4'),
        linetype=ifelse(grepl('2000',df$key),'solid','dashed')) %>% 
  layout(xaxis=list(categoryarray = month, categoryorder = "array"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
df$key <- as.factor(df$key)
df$key  <- factor(df$key , levels = c("high_2014","high_2007", "high_2000", "low_2014","low_2007", "low_2000"))
df$high_low <- substr(df$key, 1, 2)
df$high_low   <- factor(df$high_low  , levels = c("hi","lo"))
df <- df %>% arrange(high_low)


plot_ly(data=df,x=~month,y=~values,split=~key,type="scatter", mode="lines", opacity=ifelse(grepl('high',df$key),0.5,1), line=list(color='#1f77b4'),
        linetype= ~ high_low, linetypes = c('solid', 'dashed')) %>% 
  layout(xaxis=list(categoryarray = month, categoryorder = "array"))
```

[image]

Comment: perfect. Thank you. So I guess the trick is just to define everything as factor and to arrange the data according to the 'opacity-factor'

Comment: @5th Once a factor you can order it the way you want. Thanks for accepting the answer!